# How do I speed up a JSON view?

Tags: 7, caching, services

I am trying to get json response from my drupal7 site using **Views**.

```
Example : www.mysite.com/company company refers to a view which was created using json document
```

I also applied caching to the Company view as shown below
[image]

Yet, It is taking much time to load the web service. (nearly 8 sec). total records are around 200 posts. Further, the records will be increased to more number.

I also tried **Boost** module and set **max and min time for cache to 1 hour and 0 sec**. But still same problem.

I also edited .htacces file.

Can anyone suggest any solution so that i can enhance the performance of the site as well as mobile app.

Thank you

Comment: How big is the body of the response in bytes? Are you using aggregation in the view?

Comment: Yes i am using aggregation

Comment: I'm having a similar problem and am thinking aggregation may be part of the problem. I tried installed the Entity cache module to see if that would speed up the JSON generation, but not noticed an improvement. Is the output user-specific?

Comment: Yes, It is user specific. I too tried Entity Cache but no luck. planning to write queries on my own instead of views